# Extract Text From Unstructured Medical Documents For NLP

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a lot of unstructured medical documents in all sorts of different formats. 
What's the best way to parse out all the good sentences to use for NLP?

Currently I'm using SpaCy to do this, but even with multiprocessing it is pretty slow, and and the default sentence parser doesn't work 100% of the time. Here is an example of how I try and get good sentences with SpaCy:

```
def get_good_sents(texts, batch_size, n_process):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=[
        'ner',
        'entity_linker',
        'textcat',
        'entity_ruler',
        'sentencizer',
        'merge_noun_chunks',
        'merge_entities',
        'merge_subtokens',
    ])
    pipe = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=batch_size, n_process=n_process)

    rows = []
    for doc in pipe:
        clean_text = []
        for sent in doc.sents:
            struct = [token.pos_ for token in sent]
            subject = any(x in struct for x in ['NOUN', 'PRON'])
            action = any(x in struct for x in ['VERB', 'ADJ', 'AUX'])

            if subject and action :
                clean_text.append(sent.text)
        rows.append(' '.join(clean_text).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ''))

    return rows
```

Example of some text extracts

Raw Text:

```
TITLE
Patient Name:
Has a heart Condition.
Is 70 Years old.
```

Expected Output:

```
Has a heart Condition.
Is 70 Years old.
```

This examples not great because I have tons of different documents in all sort of various formats. They can really vary a lot. It basically boils down to me just wanting to strip out the boiler plate stuff and just get the actual free text.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "good sentences"? Also, your question is currently unclear in whether you would be satisfied with a speedup of the pipeline (spaCy offers [several options](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1839) to achieve better runtime performance. Or is it about the "accuracy" of your algorithm? Also please note which model you are currently using, since there is a variance in the accuracy between models.

Comment: @dennlinger I added some examples and what I am expecting. I basically want all the free text while stripping out unnecessary headers and titles. I also included the model and my current process of trying to speed things up. If I have to choose, I would prefer accuracy or speed.

Comment: Your example is actually making it harder, since it (purposefully?) includes incorrect capitalization. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Yes its to be expected. Some sentences wont start with capitalization either.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments from the above discussion, I am very confident that spaCy will not provide you with very good results, simply because it is very much tied to the expectation of a valid grammatical sentence.

At least with the current approach of looking for "correctly tagged words" in each line, I would expect this to not work very well, since tagging a sentence correctly is already tied to a decent input format;
it is once again time to quote one of my [favorite concepts in Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Depending on the accuracy you want to achieve, I would personally adopt a defensive Regex approach, where you manually sort out headings (lines with fewer than 4 words, lines that end in a colon/semicolon, etc.), although it will require significantly more effort.

Another, more direct solution would be to take what [other common boilerplate tools are doing](https://ws-dl.blogspot.com/2017/03/2017-03-20-survey-of-5-boilerplate.html), although most of those are targeted to remove boilerplate from HTML content, and thus have an easier time by utilizing tag information as well.

Comment: Love that quote. I guess I was looking for a one size fits all solution, given the amount of documents I have. Regex would require me to write a custom solution for each document.

Comment: I'm sorry that there is no better answer to your question :/ I can also recommend to scan a few of the documents and see if there is really no other solution or generalization that you can make.

Answer (score 0):

MedSpaCy's section detection can be used for this:
https://github.com/medspacy/medspacy/tree/master/notebooks/section_detection

They have some great example notebooks to structure clinical/medical text documents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).